# ORDER BY clause vs function of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

I want to use `ORDER BY` clause in functions of SQL Server. But I cannot use this, it not allow that. So, how can I use this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION PersonIDGet
    (

    )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @PersonID int;
        SET @PersonID = (SELECT PersonID FROM Person ORDER BY PersonID DESC);

        RETURN @PersonID

END
```

I got this error.

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is
>   also specified.

Comment: My guess is you probably used ORDER BY in a view, inline function, derived table, subquery, or a common table expression, and didn't specify TOP or FOR XML.  :-P

Comment: Are you returning a set of data from your function? Then let the **caller** decide on how to sort that data....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have top 1 in your select statement. You are fetching more than one row so SQL Server have trouble figuring out what PersonID will be assigned to @PersonID.

```
CREATE FUNCTION PersonIDGet
    (

    )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PersonID int;
    SET @PersonID = (SELECT TOP 1 PersonID FROM Person ORDER BY PersonID DESC);
    RETURN @PersonID
END
```